# Html to LaTex : Trademark sign not converted properly

Tags: conversion, pandoc, html

Whenever I try to convert html text which contains the trademark sign into LaTex, the trademark sign gets converted into "â„¢".

I convert a xml file to html and afterwards to latex.That's how the xml line with the trademark sign looks like:

```
Abbreviation="Test&#8482;"
```

It's converted correctly in the html file.

I tried adding these lines into my preamble file

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

but without success. It still gets converted into "â„¢"

I use pandoc to convert the html files into LaTex files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue, everything works as expected (i.e. the output is Abbreviation="Test™"). Which version of pandoc are you using, did you modify the template?

Comment: You don't explicitly say how you convert from xml to html, do you also use pandoc for that?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: The problem seems to be somewhere in your workflow: **&#8482;** appears to be converted correctly to **™** in UTF-8, which in turn is interpreted as Windows-1252 (or ISO 8859-1), hence the **â„¢**. But without code this is just elaborate guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DG's comment about the workflow I managed to find the problem:

I had a powershell script which replaced some lines in the .tex files and it messed the encoding up.

Comment: Your answer should be downvoted, because of the missing MWE!  I can't guess, how an MWE should look like, to get an trademarksign.